# Resize Scene embedded in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I've got a Swing UI and I've added a JavaFX Scene to it.
The container hierarchy looks like JPanel -> JTabbedPane -> JPanel -> JFXPanel -> Scene(LineChart)

Adding a ComponentListener to the nearest JPanel containing the Scene will report sizes with the following:

```
resizePanel = new JPanel();
resizePanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.format("JPanel:(%d,%d)\n" e.getComponent().getWidth(), getComponent().getHeight());
    }
});
```

http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/11/adding-a-window-resize-listener-to-javafx-scene/ looked promising, but it can only show the current size of the scene.  I've been using it to verify that my scenes haven't been changed.

This is my first time really working with either UI framework.

Comment: If it's your first time, I suggest to really consider using only one of those. It will be much more confusing to use both at the same time.
Why do you **need** `swing` ?

Comment: I already built most of the UI in Swing, then added LineChart<Number, Number> for graphs.

I've been using IntelliJ's UIDesigner to control layout, but it hides a lot of implementation and only does Swing.  Not the best approach, but I'm up to my neck already.

I understand the basics...they're running on separate threads so talking to each other will take more work than is obvious.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun embending of Swing this is requirement for JavaFX future, where all JavaFX fans are Bugs testers, based/with poor community to endure this testing hardship, have to waiting for JavaFX 8.1 better directy to 8.2 version

Comment: @mKorbel, still for anyone's first project I do advice from staying away from more than one framework. That being said, the JavaFX is much easier to code for a beginner than swing. (I am not saying that it is able (currently) to be the de facto standard for java applications).